# Query different columns depending on generic type argument

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I have a table with configurations and there are multiple types (stored in different columns) and i need to query with entity framework for the current type based on the generic type

I have 2 approaches 1 is just casting everything to (dynamic), basically saying i don't need type checking here

and it look like this

```
   static TValue GetValueBasedOnType<TValue>(int configKey)
    {
        var query = dbcontext.Configurations.Where(c => c.configKey == configKey);
        if(typeof(TValue) == typeof(bool))
            return (dynamic)(query.Select(c => c.ValueBit).FirstOrDefault() ?? false);
        if(typeof(TValue) == typeof(string))
            return (dynamic)(query.Select(c => c.ValueText).FirstOrDefault());
        if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(decimal))
            return (dynamic)(query.Select(c => c.ValueDecimal).FirstOrDefault());
        return default(TValue);
    }
```

Or i can just cast the query to the current type, by first making it a general object and then change it back to the original type, like this

```
    static TValue GetValueBasedOnType<TValue>(int configKey)
    {
        var query = dbcontext.Configurations.Where(c => c.configKey == configKey);
        if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(bool))
            return (TValue)(object)(query.Select(c => c.ValueBit).FirstOrDefault() ?? false);
        if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(string))
            return (TValue)(object)(query.Select(c => c.ValueText).FirstOrDefault());
        if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(decimal))
            return (TValue)(object)(query.Select(c => c.ValueDecimal).FirstOrDefault());
        return default(TValue);
    }
```

I just wonder what option is a better idea to use?

Comment: I guess, if you need an unknown (dynamic) object as return value, that'll be better to use simple `object` and leave `dynamic` for native code, COM interop.

Comment: Why not just cast directly to `TValue`?

Comment: i cant cast direct try -  it will not compile

Answer (score 1):

You can cast **directly** to `TValue` using the Linq [`Cast`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
static TValue GetValueBasedOnType<TValue>(int configKey)
{
    var query = new List<Configuration>{ new Configuration { ValueDecimal = 1.2M, ValueBit = true, ValueText = "Text" }};
    if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(bool))
        return query.Select(c => c.ValueBit).Cast<TValue>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(string))
        return query.Select(c => c.ValueText).Cast<TValue>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (typeof(TValue) == typeof(decimal))
        return query.Select(c => c.ValueDecimal).Cast<TValue>().FirstOrDefault();
    return default(TValue);
}
```

As you can see, I used a `List<Configuration>` to test your function. With the following additional code in LinqPad:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public bool ValueBit { get; set; }
    public string ValueText { get; set; }
    public decimal ValueDecimal { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    GetValueBasedOnType<bool>(0).Dump();
    GetValueBasedOnType<string>(0).Dump();
    GetValueBasedOnType<decimal>(0).Dump();
}
```

my output is, as expected:

> True
>   Text
>   1.2

Out of interest I ran a similar query against a *database* of my own in Linqpad and again I got the expected result and the SQL generated was satisfactory - a `TOP(1)` query.